# Implementing a Randomized Selection Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the randomized selection algorithm that returns the K-th largest element in an array. The algorithm in the code below works when pivot is always set to equal the first element in the array. How do I get the code to work such that it finds the K-th largest using a randomly generated pivot point ?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomizedKSelection {
private static Random generator = new Random();

public static int partition(int[] A, int start, int end) {
    // start = generator.nextInt(end); This Line breaks the code
    int pivot = A[start];
    int pivotPosition = start++;
    while (start <= end) {
        // scan for values less than the pivot
        while ((start <= end) && (A[start] < pivot)) {
            start++;
        }

        // scan for values greater than the pivot
        while ((end >= start) && (A[end] >= pivot)) {
            end--;
        }    
        if (start > end) {
            // swap the end uncoformed 
            // element with the pivot
            swap(A, pivotPosition, end); 
        }
        else {
            // swap unconformed elements:
            // start that was not lesser than the pivot 
            // and end that was not larger than the pivot
            swap(A, start, end);
        }
    }
    return end;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

// iterative version
private static int orderStatistic(int[] A, int k, int start, int end) {
    int pivotPosition = partition(A, start, end);

    while (pivotPosition != k - 1) {
        if (k - 1 < pivotPosition) {
            end = pivotPosition - 1;
        }
        else {
            start = pivotPosition + 1;
        }

        pivotPosition = partition(A, start, end);
    }

    return A[k - 1];
}

public static int kthLargest(int[] A, int k) {
    return orderStatistic(A, A.length - k + 1, 0, A.length - 1);
}

public static void swap(int[] A, int i, int j){
    int temp = A[i];
    A[i]= A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
}

}
```

Comment: Don't forget Random is not thread safe, so a static instance can cause undesired errors when used from multiple threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a `partition implementation from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort#Java). I changed your code to use 0-based indices (you can find examples for 0-based indices more easily), you can wrap them if you like (see kthLargest1Based). Small randomized test arguments the validity of the algorithm.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomizedKSelection {
    private static Random generator = new Random();

    private static int partition(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
        int index = begin + generator.nextInt(end - begin + 1);
        int pivot = array[index];
        swap(array, index, end); 
        for (int i = index = begin; i < end; ++ i) {
            if (array[i] <= pivot) {
                swap(array, index++, i);
            }
        }
        swap(array, index, end); 
        return (index);
    }

    // iterative version
    private static int orderStatistic(int[] A, int k, int start, int end) {
        int pivotPosition = partition(A, start, end);

        while (pivotPosition != k) {
            if (k < pivotPosition) {
                end = pivotPosition - 1;
            } else {
                start = pivotPosition + 1;
            }

            pivotPosition = partition(A, start, end);
        }

        return A[k];
    }

    public static int kthLargest(int[] A, int k) {
        return orderStatistic(A, A.length - k - 1, 0, A.length - 1);
    }

    public static int kthLargest1Based(int[] A, int k) {
        return kthLargest(A, k - 1);
    }

    public static int kthLargestSafe(int[] A, int k) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        return A[A.length - k - 1];
    }

    public static void swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
        int temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            int[] A = new int[1 + random.nextInt(1000)];
            int max = 1 + random.nextInt(2 * A.length); 
            for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
                A[j] = random.nextInt(max);
            }
            int k = random.nextInt(A.length);
            if (RandomizedKSelection.kthLargest(A, k) != RandomizedKSelection.kthLargestSafe(A, k)) {
                System.out.println("BUG");
            }
        }
    }

}
```